# unix - how to sort on a specific key

Tags: bash, sorting, unix, command-line

How do I sort this output?

```
10.1.3.39:{ "range_start" : 96, "range_end" : 96 }
10.1.3.27:{ "range_start" : 33, "range_end" : 33 }
10.1.3.100:{ range_start" : 30, "range_end" : 30 }
10.1.2.233:{ "range_start" : 78, "range_end" : 78 }
10.1.4.239:{ "range_start" : 53, "range_end" : 53 }
10.1.2.161:{ "range_start" : 44, "range_end" : 44 }
```

I want to sort this output by the `range_start` key

So, expected would be:

```
10.1.3.100:{ "range_start" : 30, "range_end" : 30 }
10.1.3.27:{ "range_start" : 33, "range_end" : 33 }
10.1.2.161:{ "range_start" : 44, "range_end" : 44 }
10.1.4.239:{ "range_start" : 53, "range_end" : 53 }
10.1.2.233:{ "range_start" : 78, "range_end" : 78 }
10.1.3.39:{ "range_start" : 96, "range_end" : 96 }
```

Comment: Third input line is missing a quote before `range_start`.

Comment: yeah, i fixed that in the question. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a [decorate, sort, undecorate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) pipe like so:

```
$ awk -F",|:" '{printf "%s\t%s\n", $3,$0}' file | sort -n | awk -F"\t" '{print $2}'
```

Or, if using a `\t` or other unique delimiter, you can use `cut`:

```
$ awk -F",|:" '{printf "%s\t%s\n", $3,$0}' file | sort -n | cut -f 2
```

Either case:

```
10.1.3.100:{ range_start" : 30, "range_end" : 30 }
10.1.3.27:{ "range_start" : 33, "range_end" : 33 }
10.1.2.161:{ "range_start" : 44, "range_end" : 44 }
10.1.4.239:{ "range_start" : 53, "range_end" : 53 }
10.1.2.233:{ "range_start" : 78, "range_end" : 78 }
10.1.3.39:{ "range_start" : 96, "range_end" : 96 }
```

Change the `\t` to another delimiter if there are tabs in the text data.

Answer (score 1):

Here we have a JSON-like format, not a column-formatted text, yet we can get by sorting just by a field value separated by spaces:

```
sort -n -k 4,4
```

Would produce the desired output.

However using a parser that is aware of the format would help in many cases.
For instance, the solution with `sort` would fail if the keys and values were not consistently separated by spaces, e.g.

```
0.1.3.100:{ range_start":30, "range_end" : 30 }
```

or if the order of the entries was not consistent, e.g.

```
0.1.2.233:{ "range_end" : 108, "range_start" : 78 }
10.1.3.39:{ "range_start" : 96, "range_end" : 96 }
```